# Transaction I never made

Tags: transactions

I'm a newbie so this might be a stupid question, but on Blockchain, it says I have made two transactions however I only did one transaction and the overall thing does not make sense to me. Could someone please explain where this second transaction is from and what the 10 BTC on the right means?

This is the page: https://blockchain.info/address/12b6BMrGnqm5eHiLGejWuESurbVxwVU4gk

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you told us what sort of address this is (e.g. your private wallet, an address you received money at in an online wallet, etc.) and what the transaction you *do* understand means (e.g. were you part of a bet, did you buy coins to deposit in your account, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild stab in the dark, that you are probably moving bitcoins from an exchange, because if you are new to this you are probably not making multi-party payments.

The earlier of the two transactions (green) is showing several previous addresses, paying several others. This would occur for instance when you withdraw from an exchange: ie they will be paying many people who are all making withdrawals, from coins that were deposited at many addresses.

The second payment, I am going to assume is a consolidation payment. As you say you only made one transaction, I can only think that this is either an exchange consolidating your deposit (because your first transaction was from one exchange to another), or else you withdrew to an online wallet service which is doing the same thing - consolidating. (Beware)

There is a third alternative, and that is that your machine has been compromised and you have just lost some bitcoins. I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I assume the linked address is your own.

The gray `10 BTC` shows the total amount that was sent to the recipient address: The [second, newer transaction](https://blockchain.info/de/tx/61afc1a8fd5ed1386fc463427c259cade18a0b211fb513876c433df751b818f9) associated with your address collected a total of 10 BTC from a number of different addresses in one transaction to the [receiving address](https://blockchain.info/de/address/13YC2JhGe18DrbEf7te2pPMHMRNebQvCc5), including the 0.3645 BTC from your address shown in the red box.